# Why doesn't this code check for the interface correctly?

Tags: java, interface, vector, instanceof

I thought this code would add an object to appropriate vectors, but I'm getting a null pointer exception. I know `Actor a` exists, because `actors.add(a)` is working as expected. I researched how to test whether an object implements an interface, but all the examples I could find detailed how to call a method of the interface, instead of calling a method that requires an instance of that interface.

```
public void addActor(Actor a) {
    actors.add(a); // actors is a vector
    if (a instanceof Drawable) {
        panel.addDrawable((Drawable) a);
    }
}
```

And in panel:

```
public void addDrawable(Drawable d) {
    images.add(d); // images is a vector
}
```

Comment: You can add null to vectors just fine.

Comment: I can't tell what the question is--what do you mean by "calling a method of an interface instead of calling a method that requires an instance of that interface"?

Comment: The only possible place for the NPE you are getting is (if you're saying you're positive Actor a isn't null, then the `panel.addDrawable((Drawable) a);` line has to be it. `panel` must be null, unless there is other code you aren't showing us. Showing us the exception itself would be nice.

Comment: Please show the stacktrace from the NPE.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm getting a null pointer exception. I know `Actor a` exists, because `actors.add(a)` is working as expected.

`Vector.add(null)` will not raise a `NullPointerException`.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) says

> `public boolean contains(Object o)`
>
> Returns `true` if this vector contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this vector contains at least one element e such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

Comment: Oh. Dang. Thanks. But right now I'm only calling it with `addActor(new Square());`, so I don't see how that could really be the issue. And when I remove the code referencing the interface and add System.out.println tests, everything looks like it's working.

Comment: @Techni, If the top stack from of your NPE is in that method then either `actors` or `panel` is `null`.